# How can I fix this MySQL connection error?

Tags: mysql

I tried to install and run MySQL on my mac, the installation went well, just a few clicks in dialog. Although my final goal is to invoke SQL database via Terminal, I have to configure the environment within the GUI - MySQL Workbench, anyway this is the recommended GUI by MySQL.

I made every effort but still cannot be able to start build databases, because I even cannot connect to the SQL server, not to say create user accounts. Here I tried to reset root password, and figure out if the error derives from user authority. Below are Terminal scripts and results I used (codes found from the Internet):

```
localhost:~ sattva$ cd /usr/local/mysql
localhost:mysql sattva$ scripts/mysql_install_db
WARNING: Could not write to config file ./my-new.cnf: Permission denied

Installing MySQL system tables...2015-05-05 10:00:41 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-05-05 10:00:41 0 [Note] ./bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.24) starting as process 1738 ...
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64/data/localhost.lower-test
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64/data/localhost.lower-test
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] Binlog end
2015-05-05 10:00:41 1738 [Note] ./bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

localhost:mysql sattva$ ./bin/mysql_secure_installation
ERROR: can't create .my.cnf.1739: Permission denied at ./bin/mysql_secure_installation line 105.
Cleaning up...
Warning: Could not unlink .my.cnf.1739: No such file or directory
Warning: Could not unlink .mysql.1739: No such file or directory
```

There are to many warnings and errors, what is wrong? Is something about my system? Or did I installed MySQL incorrectly? Anyway I downloaded the dmg file from MySQL's website; and I've checked the file's MD5, it's totally the same with that on MySQL's webpage.

Comment: Could you try `$> sudo scripts/mysql_install_db` instead of `$> scripts/mysql_install_db`?

Comment: looks like a permission issue...Are you sure mysql can read and write my.cnf file???